# 502 Bad Gateway when callback from proxy

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, oauth-2.0, kibana, amazon-eks

I am using oauth2 proxy to authenticate the user through google and then the authenticated user should connect to kibana which can be accessed via `http://localhost:5601`. However after authentication success (as mentioned in the 1st log), it gives `502 Bad gateway: There was a problem connecting to the upstream server`.. Any ideas whats the problem here ?

The oauth2-proxy logs are looking like this:

```
10.20.51.169:5475- user@example.com[2022/05/10 11:12:40] [AuthSuccess] Authenticated via OAuth2: Session{email:user@example.com user:656549595959595 PreferredUsername: token:true id_token:true created:2022-05-10 11:12:40.385971851 +0000 UTC m=+2147.975924036 expires:2022-05-10 12:12:39.385971851 +0000 UTC m=+5746.975924036 refresh_token:true}

10.20.51.169:5475  - - [2022/05/10 11:12:40] kibana.sandbox.k8s.example.com GET - "/oauth2/callback?state=fefef5awef5aew:/&code=4/6a5wf650aw6f56we6f56aew6f5a60fwe56af5fa2ew6f0ef=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20openid&authuser=0&hd=example.com&prompt=consent" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36" 302 24 0.163

[2022/05/10 11:12:40] [error_page.go:93] Error proxying to upstream server: EOF

10.20.51.169:5475 - fawef-awef-awef-awef-FE - user@example.com [2022/05/10 11:12:40] kibana.sandbox.k8s.example.com GET / "/" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36" 502 2163 0.001
```

I am using ECK operator and the kibana.yml file is looking like this:

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  version: 8.2.0
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: LoadBalancer
        ports:
        - name: https
          port: 443
          targetPort: 3000
      metadata:
        annotations:
          # Note that the backend talks over HTTP.
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
          # TODO: Fill in with the ARN of your certificate.
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:***
          # Only run SSL on the port named "https" below.
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        subjectAltNames:
        - dns: kibana.sandbox.k8s.example.com      
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: kube-es
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 1Gi
            cpu: 0.5
          limits:
            memory: 2.5Gi
            cpu: 2
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5601
            name: http
            protocol: TCP
      - name: kibana-proxy
        image: 'quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest'
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
          - --cookie-secret=sergawergawgr4agrgargrgarg=
          - --client-id=872911544486-otlttds9nh9t6h2ifovba0kcd6sa3seb.apps.googleusercontent.com
          - --client-secret=iijIIIIJIIE_EDEWQID_DQWDWQD
          - --upstream=http://localhost:5601
          - --email-domain=example.com
          - --footer=-
          - --http-address=http://:3000
          - --redirect-url=https://kibana.sandbox.k8s.example.com/oauth2/callback
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
            name: http
            protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 256Mi
```

Let me know if anything is needed. Thanks

Comment: i dont know the role of parametre: upstream, can you try without

Comment: It gives 404 error.

Comment: Oauth2 documentation says this:
`the http url(s) of the upstream endpoint, file:// paths for static files or static://<status_code> for static response. Routing is based on the path`